# Can I generate JSON from "Classic" ASP on IIS?

Tags: javascript, iis, windows-7, asp-classic

I have some logic I want to run on the server-side.  It's implemented in Javascript, and I'd like to use it to generate and emit JSON, to allow a REST-api for a web app I'm producing.

Development is on Windows7 and IIS.  I know IIS still supports ASP, which can be implemented in Javascript.

Is it possible for an ASP classic page to emit JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, no problem.  It's possible to use the well-known json2.js from [json.org](http://json.org) within a Javascript-based "classic ASP" page.

Per ejemplo:

```
<%@ language="Javascript" %>

<script language="Javascript" runat="server" src='json2.js'></script>
<script language="Javascript" runat="server">

(function() {

    scriptEngineInfo = function () {
        var s = {
            engine : ScriptEngine(),
            version: {
                major: ScriptEngineMajorVersion(),
                minor:ScriptEngineMinorVersion()
            },
            build: ScriptEngineBuildVersion()
        };
        return s;
    }

}());


var x = scriptEngineInfo();
var d = new Date();
x.Timestamp = d.valueOf();

Response.Write (JSON.stringify(x));

</script>
```

Comment: ...but why? Hey, are you the IIRF guy?

Comment: Why *what*?  (Yes, I am the IIRF guy)

Comment: I'm sorry, just dying to know why classic ASP.

Comment: Sometimes I just wanna write javascript! Javascript everywhere!

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic example of how to create a `.json` file with classic `ASP`.

```
<%
Response.ContentType = "application/json"
Response.Write("{ ""responseCode"": ""success"", ""accountNumber"": ""78527511"", ""ID_Code"": ""654321"", ""version"": ""1""}")
%>
```

having as a result:

```
{
  "responseCode": "success", 
  "accountNumber": "78527511", 
  "ID_Code": "654321",  
  "version": "1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great article on it which includes some example code:  http://www.webdevbros.net/2007/04/26/generate-json-from-asp-datatypes/
Its best to put you data in a properly structured array and this code will show you have to take an array and output JSON formatted text.