# Autosuggest to work with JSON

Tags: jquery, json, asp-classic, autosuggest

Allthough JQuery has en autosuggest function, the Drew Wilson version forked by [Wu Yuntao](https://github.com/wuyuntao/jquery-autosuggest) is more versatile.

However I cannot make it work when referencing an external data source

To make it very simple:

Client part:

```
<!doctype HTML><meta charset="UTF-8"><HEAD>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.autoSuggest.css?v=1">
<script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.autoSuggest.js"></script>
</head><Body>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=text]").autoSuggest("http://localhost/test/FindData.asp", {selectedItemProp: "name", searchObjProps: "name"});
})                          
</script>
Testing:
<form><input type=text></form></body>
```

And the datasource made very simple:

```
<%
response.contentType = "application/json"
JSON= "{""items"": [{""value"": ""21"", ""name"": ""Mick Jagger""},{""value"": ""43"", ""name"": ""Johnny Storm""}]}"
response.write JSON
%>
```

Which yields:

```
{"items": [{"value": "21", "name": "Mick Jagger"},{"value": "43", "name": "Johnny Storm"}]}
```

What have I missed?

Comment: The missing `"`, hence the "strange" syntax highlighting in the last code block ;)

Comment: [Can I generate JSON from “Classic” ASP on IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746000/can-i-generate-json-from-classic-asp-on-iis)

Comment: Yes, a missing quote after the first value.

Comment: @Andreas: the missing quotes around 'text' is allowed and changed nothing, and yes, JSON with with classic ASP is no problem.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf, yes there is a typing error in the missing quotes at the end of 'Value'. However that changed noting. The dataset validates with no problem on online validators.

Comment: @PC-Gram  So what actual issue are you having?  What is your expected result vs actual.  What error message if any do you get?

Comment: @PC-Gram  And no, you can't have unmatched quotes, that will stuff it up.  You have a "value:"21"    Note that there is a quote missing after value.  If you mean you can have "value":21   Then yes.  but you must have a ending quote for "value

Comment: @Dijkgraaf: I get no error message at all. It just ain't working.

Answer (score 1):

Your datasource needs to be changed to have a quote after the first *value* string.

```
<%
response.contentType = "application/json"
JSON= "{""items"": [{""value"": ""21"", ""name"": ""Mick Jagger""},{""value"": ""43"", ""name"": ""Johnny Storm""}]}"
response.write JSON
%>
```

Otherwise it is not valid JSON

Comment: Yes, I know, and it is actually just a typo in my original question. I fixed it, but to no avail although the output did validate with no errors. I've corrected the question now.

Comment: Finally I found the answer: Stripping "items" made it work. The JSON should simply look like:
[{"value": "21", "name": "Mick Jagger"},{"value": "43", "name": "Johnny Storm"}].
That's however in contradiction with documentation for the function.